# Using AVExportSession to rewrite ID3 tags of mp3 file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm attempting to rewrite the ID3 tags of mp3 files in the Documents folder of my app. Surprisingly it seems that Apple has little to no prewritten code for writing metadata. It appears the AVExportSession could be a viable route, albeit a circuitous one...it would basically involve reading the data from the existing mp3 and writing it to a new mp3 file with the updated metadata, though it seems like there should be an easier way to do this. Any help with this process or suggestions as to an easier method will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it helps at all, the mp3 files are represented as AVURLAsset objects...

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [AVMetaDataItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVMetadataItem) class? According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), this is used to set Metadata for AVAssets.